# How to exclude resources during packaging with SBT but not during testing

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a bunch of conf files in a project structure like this:

```

```
src / main / resources / live.conf
src / test / resources / test.conf
```

```

I want to excluded live.conf from the artifact that is build when I run sbt one-jar (using the one-jar plugin). I added this line which unfortunately also excludes test.conf when running sbt test:compile

`excludeFilter in Runtime in unmanagedResources := "*.conf"`

How can I exclude live.conf in the artifact jar but not for the tests?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should help:

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= { _.filter(!_._1.getName.endsWith(".conf")) }
```

`packageBin` is a task which produces your jar artifact and `mappings` denotes files wich are used for compilation and project packaging in `Compile` scope

Comment: @4lex1v I tried your suggestion in build.st for a Scala Play 2 with Akka project created from  Typesafe activator 1.3.2 templates. Each time I run the activator `compile` and then the `package` command, the resultant jar file contains my `application.conf` file in the base dir inside the jar file. Are you aware of any changes? Do you have any advice? thx.

Comment: How can I add more extension? I try

   mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= { _.filter(!_._1.getName.endsWith(".properties") || !_._1.getName.endsWith(".xml")) }

but that doesn't working

Comment: @carfield I would make a list with various extensions, and call `.contains` on it

Comment: Problem: When I do `sbt run`, the excluded files are also not present. How can I fix that? (Tried with SBT 1.0.2 and 1.0.3)