# How to exclude files under conf folder for distribution?

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.3

I have a `application.dev.conf` and `application.test.conf` under my `conf` folder in my Play 2.3 application but I do not want it to be packaged as part of my distribution? What is the right `excludeFilter` for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `mappings` to exclude both files.

```
mappings in Universal := {
  val origMappings = (mappings in Universal).value
  origMappings.filterNot { case (_, file) => file.endsWith("application.dev.conf") || file.endsWith("application.test.conf") }
}
```

Comment: This only removes them from the dist task, they still seem to be present in the `.jar` file of the project?!

Answer (score 5):

Actually lpiepiora's answer will do the trick, however note that filtering on `mappings in Universal` will only exclude `application.dev.conf` from the `conf` folder **and NOT from the jar itself.**

I don't know about the `play` framework but in general if you have something like this:

```
hello
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── scala
│       │   └── com.world.hello
│       │       └── Main.scala
│       ├── resources
│       │   ├── application.dev.conf
│       │   └── application.conf
```

Doing:

```
mappings in (Universal, ) ++= {
  ((resourceDirectory in Compile).value * "*").get.filterNot(f => f.getName.endsWith(".dev.conf")).map { f =>
    f -> s"conf/${f.name}"
  }
}
```

would produce the following package structure:

```
hello/
├── lib
│   └── com.world.hello-1234-SNAPSHOT.jar
├── conf
│   └── application.conf
```

However if you look into the jar, you will see that your `dev.conf` file is still in there:

```
$ unzip -v com.world.hello-1234-SNAPSHOT.jar
Archive:  com.world.hello-1234-SNAPSHOT.jar
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
     371  Defl:N      166  55% 10-01-2018 15:20 36c30a78  META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
       0  Stored        0   0% 10-01-2018 15:20 00000000  com/
       0  Stored        0   0% 10-01-2018 15:20 00000000  com/world/
       0  Stored        0   0% 10-01-2018 15:20 00000000  com/world/hello/
       0  Stored        0   0% 10-01-2018 15:20 00000000  com/world/hello/
   13646  Defl:N     4361  68% 10-01-2018 12:06 7e2dce2f  com/world/hello/Main$.class
     930  Defl:N      445  52% 10-01-2018 13:57 5b180d92  application.conf
     930  Defl:N      445  52% 10-01-2018 13:57 5b180d92  application.dev.conf
```

This is actually not really harmful but if you want to remove them too, here is the answer: [How to exclude resources during packaging with SBT but not during testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491505/how-to-exclude-resources-during-packaging-with-sbt-but-not-during-testing)

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= { _.filter(!_._1.getName.endsWith(".dev.conf")) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Does an `excludeFilter` as follows work for you?

```
excludeFilter in Universal in unmanagedResources := "application.dev.conf" || "application.test.conf"
```

(The `unmanagedResourceDirectories` key refers to `conf/` by default.)