# How to ignore the /conf folder from being packaged in a Play application?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

When creating a distributable application using 'play dist' the contents of the /conf folder is packaged and also put into the jar..

I am wondering why this is? And if there is a way of skipping the conf folder when doing a play dist. I would like to have the contents only in the jar file.

We are using Play 2.2.4

Comment: Add tag with Play version

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exclude files under conf folder for distribution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375624/how-to-exclude-files-under-conf-folder-for-distribution)

Answer (score 2):

Acording to **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24380098/1066240)** you need to add these lines to your `built.sbt`:

```
mappings in Universal := {
  val origMappings = (mappings in Universal).value
  origMappings.filterNot { case (_, file) => file.endsWith("application.conf") }
}
```

Comment: Excuse for the dumb question, but i need to do this in a build.scala, how can this be done?

Comment: no, `built.sbt` it should be in main folder of the project isn't it?

Comment: Just want to say that this is really helpful to exclude ebextension files that shouldn't be deployed to amazon. AWS reads .ebextensions recursively and so if you store different files for different environments in your conf directory you get all kinds of wacky stuff if you deploy without filtering those file a `file.contains(ebextensions)`