# SBT: subproject specific log configuration via logback.xml resource

Tags: logging, sbt

I have an SBT build with the following structure:

```
lazy val Core   = project
lazy val Server = project dependsOn(Core)
```

In Core, I have a command line utility that logs using logback. In Server, I also log using logback, but I need a logback.xml configuration **different** from the one in Core.

How can I have two logback.xml resources, one for each project, in a way that in Server only one logback.xml resource is in the classpath. (By default, the dependsOn puts Core's logback.xml in the Server project's classpath as well, resulting in logback warning me about multiple logback.xml resources in project Server).

My primary concern with this is the classpath of "sbt run".

Lateron, I am also looking for ways to exclude the resources from packaged jars, but it looks like that can be achieved like this: [How to exclude resources during packaging with SBT but not during testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491505/how-to-exclude-resources-during-packaging-with-sbt-but-not-during-testing).

Comment: Do you need the logback.xml files inside jar files?

Comment: No, the logback.xml files should be kept out of the jar files (because users might want to edit them).

Comment: Do you want to include logback.xml's or not? If not, move it from `src/main/resources` as described in http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html#Change+the+default+resource+directory.

Comment: No, the logback xml files should not be included in the JARs. Thank you, your hint pointed in the right direction (although I still had some way to go to get it working).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution that works for me. In each subproject using log4j, I add `fullClasspath in Runtime += baseDirectory.value / "conf"` to the build.sbt file. That way,

- the logback.xml can be put in the "conf" directory of the subproject
- "sbt run" in the subproject finds the logback.xml
- the logback.xml is excluded from the JAR packaging.

Of course, when publishing the full product, you have to configure the packaging tool to put a logback.xml file somewhere sensible.