# scala / sbt: How to build two JARs with identical content, except one JAR should exclude .conf files from resources

Tags: scala, sbt

We are using sbt as build tool for our scala project.
My question is how to build two JARs with identical content, except one JAR should exclude .conf files from resources?

I tried it with

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= { _.filter(!_._1.getName.endsWith(".conf")) }
```

i found here on stackoverflow but it will exclude the conf files in general.

I am new to scala and sbt, I read about multi module/project, maybe this can help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491505/how-to-exclude-resources-during-packaging-with-sbt-but-not-during-testing

from here i got the code snippet